# Why use hidden_field_tag instead of f.hidden_field in edit action of password_reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing chap12: Password Reset in rails railstutorial.org and i saw this code
`app/views/password_resets/edit.html.erb`

```
<h1>Reset password</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `PasswordResetsController`
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by email: params[:email]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by email: params[:email]
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      add_errors
    elsif @user.update_attributes user_params
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = t "controllers.password_reset.success"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

end
```

Reset link like this: `http://localhost:3000/password_resets/DCxf-6H4fyBf32QrW-d2Zg/edit?email=trag08%40gmail.com`
When click link, route call action `edit` and get email to params[:email] and view `edit.html.erb` and put email into hiddren field. And why in this code, they don't use `f.hidden_field :email, @user.email`.

I try use `f.hidden_field :email, @user.email` and edit update action in controller like this.

```
def update
        @user = User.find_by email: params[:user][:email]
        if params[:user][:password].empty?
```

Rails rase error: `undefined method`merge' for "xxx@gmail.com":String`, and it's not get user. Why like this? .

Answer (score 2):

As you see in the tutorials example `<%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>` is not creating a param that's available in `params[:user]`.

It's creating a param **that's available in `params[:email]`**

When they call the email they use:

`@user = User.find_by email: params[:email]`

You use:

`@user = User.find_by email: params[:user][:email]`

---

I would recommend looking into what exactly is created by a rails helper tag as the one you're using. See [Form Tag Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html).

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the answer if it helped you with your problem.